# Sort array on PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So, I have this structure on an Array on PHP and I was wondering how to sort the values:

```
    Array
   (
       [0] => Array
       (
           [0] => One
           [1] => Ultra
           [2] => Plus
       )

       [1] => Array
       (
           [0] => Value
           [1] => Another value
       )

       [2] => Array
       (
           [0] => buzz
           [1] => fuzz
           [2] => bla
           [3] => bla
           [4] => blabla
       )
   )
```

I tried using  `array_multisort` but it says: `Message: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent`

I expect every subarray sorted alphabetically. actual code:

```
array_multisort($array[0], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $array[1], 
                           SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $array[2], 
                           SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING);
```

Comment: 1. Please show us your code 2. What is the expected + current output?

Comment: There is a [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29926285/edit) button for your question. You're free to use it :)

Comment: `array_walk($myArray, function(&$value) { sort($value); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a foreach:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array);$i++)
{
  $low_array[$i ] = array_map('strtolower', $array[$i ]);
  array_multisort($array[$i], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $array[$i]);
}
```

And this way the Warning doesn't show. :)